# Setting border using jquery css on IE7 is taking a very long time

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, border

I am using HTTPWatch in IE7 to determine why one of my pages is loading so slow.  This only happens in IE7, not any other browser.  I narrowed it down to one jquery line which sets a border on two containers.

When I comment out the second line the page loads significantly faster in IE7 - 2 seconds compared to 7.

```
  $('.ccl, .ccr').css({'min-height':maxHeight});
  $('.ccl, .ccr').css({'border':'1px solid #ccc'});
```

I've never experienced this before and would like to find out if anyone else has seen this and why this is happening.  There is nothing wrong with the code, it works, just slowly.

Comment: Get into the habit of caching your selectors (As shown in Mythril's answer). Traversing through the DOM repetitively can get very expensive, specially if you selecting by class possibly selecting/re-selecting tons of elements each time. Caching is cheap, constant traversal of the DOM is not.

Comment: Thanks, I should add that the slowness occurs even if I change the line to be as such: $('.ccl,.ccr').css({'min-height':maxHeight,'border':'1px solid #ccc'});

Comment: Another option is to not use inline styles. I don't know how slow/fast jQuery's `css` is given a specific number of elements but using `addClass` instead, adding a class referencing those styles in a style sheet may be faster. For example `$('.ccl, .ccr').addClass('myNewClass')`, combine that with caching the selector and `if(!cachedSeletor.hasClass('myNewClass')){...addClass('...')}`.

Comment: I agree with what François says. However, if CSS is not an option, maybe you could try specifying each border-* property separately instead of using the shorthand.

Comment: Thanks, I am using addClass now instead of setting the border.  Back to my original question though  - Why does setting the border take 5 seconds??  That is crazy slow.

Comment: Are you testing locally or on a server? Server response times vary. I don't think this is a rendering issue, but I don't have IE7 handy to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
var cached = $('.ccl, .ccr');
cached.css({'min-height':maxHeight});
cached.css({'border':'1px solid #ccc'});
```

Comment: The selector is not the issue.  It's the setting of the border that is causing IE7 to slow down.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the element name then IE7 can discard anything that is not a div (this has a small performance hit in modern browsers though). Put your CSS properties in one object too.

```
$('div.ccl, div.ccr').css({
    'min-height':maxHeight,
    'border':'1px solid #ccc'
});
```

Better yet, if the elements are unique for the page (looks like `.ccl` and `.ccr` are column names) you can add an id and this will be the fastest solution:

```
$('#ccl, #ccr').css({
    'min-height':maxHeight,
    'border':'1px solid #ccc'
});
```

If you have pinpointed the problem to adding borders, then add a class and let your stylesheet handle it:

```
/* styles.css */

.ccl.border, .ccr.border {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* site.js */
$('div.ccl, div.ccr').css('min-height', maxHeight).addClass('border');
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code.  It works.  It is just slow.  My question is - Why?  Why does setting the border using .css in IE7 take 5 seconds?